# Camel + Jackson : Register a module for all deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, apache-camel

I'm using Camel for my application, and messages come in to routes as JSON.  I use JACKSON as my deserializer.  I have a case where I require a custom serializer/deserializer to handle one of my messages.

What I want to do is register the custom serializer/deserializer for keys.  In Camel, how do I make sure that the serializer/deserializer is available for whenever I marshall/unmarshall in my routes?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but keys (for `java.util.Map`s) are handled by separate deserializers and deserializers than values. This because they only map to/from JSON Strings. So you use different registration methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can define what dataformat you want using

```
.unmarshal(<dataFormatComponent>)
```

http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html

http://camel.apache.org/json.html